# Navigation for book collections

Tags: nodes, navigation

I'm working in a projet where I have to show a collection of books. In this website I managed using the books navigation block, for one collection with many books, with css I managed to set a tree view and indication where you are, but only allows one collection of books.
The problem is that I have to make as least 23 collections, each of them belonging to a province.

Is there a way to replicate that book navigation for each collection?
Could I make them with block menu with tree view and the same CSS style?
I think the concept of book collections is missing, from the editorial point of view.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather try to use the [Views Accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accordion) module. Here is a screenprint of what you can get from it (from its project page):

[image]

If your question is about D7, you may also want to add the [Views Nested Accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_nested_accordion) module. Here is a screenprint of what you can get from it (from its project page):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your replay. But I thinks is not the soluction,  showing content is not a problem, separate collections navigation menu is what I need. We tolk about collections of book that it have moore than 100 pages. I thing what you suggetst is for FAQs.